# Jquery binding event that has been disabled before

Tags: jquery, events, backbone.js, addition, handlers

I would like to temporary disabling a click event on a JQuery element, bound with jstree and Backbone.View.delegateEvents().

Below is how I process to do

before disabling the event, I record the event in a local variable using

```
self.defaultClick = $(this).data('events').click[0];
```

after, I disable the click event using

```
$(this).click(false);
```

Now I need to be bound again, I assign it back to the element using

```
$(this).data('events').click = self.defaultClick;
```

That works good, until the second time.

I get this error from JQuery.event.add 'Object # has no method 'push'' at this line

```
handlers.push( handleObj );
```

The problem is 'handlers' becomes the event itself after the second assignment, while it s an array at the first assignment.

Any idea, how can I get around ? 
either by avoiding reassign the event after being sure it s already bound, or may be using another way to assign the event ?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT

I am using jstree on this application.
I bound specific events on css class but, regarding the state of the application, I need to be able of disabling all the tree (including the class that are bound previously).

Comment: Why no cache your events function in a variable and just use `on` and `off` to attach/detach the event? `var foo = function(){}; $el.on('click.foo', foo); $el.off('click.foo')`

Comment: As I said, I don't have the function that should be triggered at this point of the application. The view managing the tree being another one that the one that provide the function to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding/unbinding a handler is expensive; why not just use a delegated event handler, set to run for a particular class name (e.g. `.executeState`) -- then you can control whether or not to run the code simply by toggling the class: `$(element).toggleClass('executeState');`

This way, only a single handler is bound, only once, to the `document` (or any parent element of the element you're targeting).

```
$(document).on('click', '.executeState', function() {
    // handler for click event
});
```

Comment: I was focus on the problem and unable to clearly see how to fix it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just maintain some var to control if the event will be execute? Somehting like:

```
var runEventFor = {};

runEventFor[ "myComponent" ] = true;
$( "#myComponent" ).click(function(evt){
    if ( runEventFor[ $(this).attr("id") ] ) {
        // code to run...
    }
});
```

When you don't whant the event to execute, just set `runEventFor[ "myComponent" ]` to false. I think that in your case this approach is simpler than bind/unbind events.

Comment: Sorry, I pushed the stack before finishing to write it, now, it's up to date. Actually I don't have the method that is used at this point of the application, as it was bound using delegateEvents of a Backbone View.